# custom JS file prevents jquery from running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working to get the jQuery UI Tabs to work with a site I'm working on. I was able to get it to work after commenting out a custom made javascript file that stops jQuery from running. I need to use this file but I am not sure what is wrong with the code that would keep jQuery from running. I would be grateful for any help. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
initLimitedTextarea();
initPointsControls();
});

function initForms( id ){
$(id).bind('submit', function() {
    if(id.toString().toLowerCase() == '#fm-registration'){
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({ success: FinishRegistration });
    } else if(id.toString().toLowerCase() == '#fm-join') {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({ success: FinishJoin });
    } else {
        console.log('Initializing...');
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({ success: showResponse });
    }
    return false;
});
}

function FinishRegistration(responseText, statusText){
if(responseText.search(/NewNotify/) != -1 ){
    $('#fm-registration').hide('slow').EffectChain({onComplete:function(){
        $('#fm-registration').html(responseText);
        $('#fm-registration').show('slow');
    }}); 
} else {
    showResponse(responseText, statusText);
}
}

function showResponse(responseText, statusText)  {
if(responseText != '') { 
    $('#error-msg').html(responseText);
} else {
    tb_remove();
}
}

function FinishJoin(responseText, statusText)  {
//console.log(responseText);
if(responseText != '' && responseText.toLowerCase().search('viewtribe.php') == -1) { 
    $('#error-msg').html(responseText);
} else {
    tb_remove();
    window.location.href = responseText;
}
}

function hidePopup(){
$('#fade-area').animate({opacity:0}, 'fast').hide();
$('#container').html('&nbsp;');
//$('#container').fadeOut();
}

var specialKeys = [8,46,37,39,38,40,27,9,16,17,18,20,144];

function isSpecialKey(code){
for(i = 0; i < specialKeys.length; i++){
    if(code == specialKeys[i]){ return true; }
}
return false;
}

function initLimitedTextarea(){
$('textarea.limited-size, input.limited-size').each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('edit')){
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-monitor').html($(this).attr('size'));
        $(this).keypress(function(e){

            if(((parseInt($(this).attr('size')) - ($(this).val()).length)) <= 0 && !(specialKey = isSpecialKey(e.keyCode))){
                return false;
            }
        });
        $(this).keyup(function(e){
            $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-monitor').html((parseInt($(this).attr('size')) - ($(this).val()).length));               
        });
    }else{

        $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-monitor').html($(this).attr('cols'));
        $(this).keypress(function(e){
            if(((parseInt($(this).attr('cols')) - ($(this).val()).length)) <= 0 && !(specialKey = isSpecialKey(e.keyCode))){
                return false;
            }
        });
        $(this).keyup(function(e){
            $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-monitor').html((parseInt($(this).attr('cols')) - ($(this).val()).length));
        });
    }
});
}

function initPointsControls(){
$("input[name=completed[]], input[name=targeted[]]").each(function (i, el) {
    $(el).bind('click', function(){
        name = ($(this).attr('name').toLowerCase() == 'completed[]') ? 'targeted[]' : 'completed[]' ;
        if($(this).attr('checked') == true && $("input[name=" + name + "][value=" + $(this).attr('value') + "]").attr('checked') == true){
            $("input[name=" + name + "][value=" + $(this).attr('value') + "]").attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
}

function Activate( obj ){
$("#activation-done").load($(obj).attr('href'));

return false;
}

function delayer(){
window.location = 'GetRewards.php';
}

function confirmation() {
var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to use reward points for this reward?');
if (answer){
    setTimeout('delayer()', 1000);
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
}

function SetData( value ){ $("input[name='profileimage']").val(value); }

function enableSubmit() { $('input[name="submitnew"]').attr('disabled', !$('#agree').attr('checked')); }
```

Comment: Try using $.noConflict(); see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: In which order are you loading the files? If you load this one before jQuery, $ will be undefined by that time. Also, are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I tried using noConflict and it did not work.

Comment: My JS flow: 1. css3-mediaqueries - 2. jquery1.10.2 - 3. jquery-ui and then a few other JS files like the placeholder patch. No errors showing in web console.